# Apache2 and multiple sites location

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server

I want to host the domains example.com, example.org and example.net on my ubuntu Server using one IP address (ie vhosts) provided by my hosting.

What I could like to know is where to actually place the public files? Most guides recommend either /var/www/example.com or /home/example.com but they don't really explain why.

Is there a best practice for this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, you can place the files wherever you want.

The Unix/Linux filesystem layout standard ([FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html)) includes specific uses for where things go, based on the idea that certain directories could be mounted read-only, some intermittently available, some shared between systems with different CPUs, etc..

Based on the standard, /home is for user directories and programs shouldn't rely on it.  /usr is read-only, and /var is for data that might change.

My recommendation: Use the directory your distribution uses.  In the case of virtualhosts, directories underneath it.  That ensures the least likelihood of causing a bad interaction with any other software on the system.

Ubuntu uses /var/www, so use /var/www/example.com.  Work with your Linux distribution, not against it.

Answer (score 0):

The [FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#HOMEUSERHOMEDIRECTORIES) indicates that `/home` should be for USER home directories. I would strongly recommend keeping sites that are not specific to a user in `/var/www`.